# Enable submit button only when no error is found

Tags: javascript, form-submit, short-circuiting

I have a simple application in which I only want to enable the calculate button only when no-errors are found (an error is recorded if the value is not a number, or a value is less than 0). I perform a few conditional checks using && and || operator. However, when only one input has been filled properly, without errors, the button is enabled. But, when an explicit wrong value has been specified the button is disabled again.

Code: https://github.com/KaustubhMaladkar/Tip-Calculator

```js
    if (!peopleError && !billError) {       
      submit.removeAttribute("disabled");
    }
    if (billError || peopleError) submit.setAttribute("disabled", "")
```

Live site: https://kaustubhmaladkar.github.io/Tip-Calculator/

Comment: you probably do not issue a error for missing inputs. so you should also check people && bill in you first if. the second if could just be an else case

Comment: @Nestoro that is working good but, with one problem. If I enter 0, in one input and after that I enter 1 another input, my button is enabled

Comment: that is probably caused by the value being stored as a string. with strings the rule is !!"0" === !!"1" && !!"0" === true, only a empty string like "" will be equal false

Comment: @Nestro, kindly explain further and tell me what be done to prevent this

Comment: you could specifically check for "0" if you want to treat it as a missing value. or use Number(bill) and Number(people) to treat "0" as the number 0. all explanation regarding type corrections can be found here: https://dev.to/promhize/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascripts-implicit-coercion-e23 (check out the section 'falsy and truthy' for this specific case)

Comment: @Nestoro. I don't why or what, I will need to read your article for that, but it works! I had been avoiding coercion for a long time. Time I start reading on that. How can I close this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to thank that @Nestoro for their comments on my question as most, if not all, of my answer is based their comments.

This code will solve the problem

```js
if (!peopleError && !billError && Number(billElem.value) && Number(peopleElem.value)) submit.removeAttribute("disabled");
else submit.setAttribute("disabled", "");
```